# R grepl - Matching Pattern to String

Tags: r, string, pattern-matching, grepl

I am using grepl() in R to match patterns to a string.

I need to match multiple strings to a common string and return TRUE if they all match.

For example:

```
a <- 'DEARBORN TRUCK INCDBA'
b <- 'DEARBORN TRUCK INC DBA'
```

I want to see if all words in variable b are also in variable a.

I can't just use grepl(b, a) because the patterns (spaces) aren't the same.

It seems like it should be something like this:

```
grepl('DEARBORN&TRUCK&INC&DBA', a)
```

or

```
grepl('DEARBORN+TRUCK+INC+DBA', a)
```

but neither work. I need to compare each individual word in b to a. In this case, since all the words exist in a, it should return TRUE.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `strsplit` to split `b` into words and then use `sapply` to perform a `grepl` on each such word.  The result will be a logical vector and if its all TRUE then return TRUE:

```
all(sapply(strsplit(b, " ")[[1]], grepl, a))
```

giving:

```
[1] TRUE
```

**Note:**  If you are only looking to determine if `a` and `b` are the same aside from spaces then remove the spaces from both and compare what is left:

```
gsub(" ", "", a) == gsub(" ", "", b)
```